# Unable to find a specification for `SwiftJSON (= 3.1.4)`

Tags: cocoapods, swifty-json

Error while installing cocoa pods in my Xcode project
Unable to find a specification for `SwiftJSON (= 3.1.4)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy / paste your code and errors message instead images.

Answer (score 4):

Framework you want to use is called `SwiftyJSON`, not `SwiftJSON`

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'
```

Also the newest version of `SwiftyJSON` is **4.2.0**, so you should use this version and then there is no need to specify version

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```